# Calculate a sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos\frac{k\pi}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have to calculate a sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\cos\frac{k\pi}{6}$. Our lecturer told us we should use de Moivre formula. But i think this sum deosnt even converge...

Comment: The sum does not converge (because $\cos \frac {k\pi}6 \nrightarrow 0$). It takes cyclic values, as you can easily check by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As $\cos\left(\pi-x\right)=-\cos x,$

$\cos\left(\pi-\dfrac{k\pi}6\right)=\cos\dfrac{(6-k)\pi}6=-\cos\dfrac{k\pi}6$

So, $\sum_{r=6k}^{6k+5}\cos\dfrac{r\pi}6=0$

So, the sum $\sum_{r=0}^n\cos\dfrac{r\pi}6$ will be oscillatory as $n\to\infty$  with $n\equiv0,1,2,3,4,5\pmod6$